# flutter Listview itemextent

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm struggling with the `ListView`.
My problem is that I've a `Listview` inside another `Listview` and the second `Listview` items height are not always the same. I want to get rid of the `itemExtent` and create an automatically height for the first `Listview`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQKvQ.png]

What I really want to acomplish is something like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ziFx.jpg]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              key: new Key("ditisdekeyvoordelistview"),
              itemBuilder: _makeMovieList,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              itemCount: _movies.length,
              itemExtent: 300.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }
//FIRST LIST
  Widget _makeMovieList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        leading: Container(
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                _movies[index].movieImage,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 100.0,
              )
            ])),
        title: Text(
          _movies[index].movieTitle,
        ),
        subtitle: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            _makeStarRating(_movies[index].movieRating),
            Text(_movies[index].movieDescription),
            _makeCardDates(index)
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
//SECOND LIST
  Widget _makeCardDates(int index) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        itemCount: _movies[index].dateTimeList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, indexx) {
          return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print(_movies[index].dateTimeList[indexx].toString());
              },
              child: Card(
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(64, 75, 96, .9),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(_movies[index].cinema),
                      Text(((dateFormatMovieHours
                          .format(_movies[index].dateTimeList[indexx]))
                          .toString())),
                    ],
                  )));
        },
        itemExtent: 40.0,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: And what happens if you remove `itemExtent`? And why do you need `Container` inside `_makeMovieList`? Return `ListTile`

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky i will get an error. The container was there temporarily, so i removed it now.

Comment: add Shrinkwrap:true in Second List & remove itemExtent

Comment: @anmol.majhail The first list still has an itemExtent, so i'm still stuck with the same problem

Comment: there should be a finite height to each widget in a listView

Answer (score 3):

Using `itemExtent` on a `ListView` isn't required, though ListView needs to have a finite height set for vertical scroll (default) and finite width is needed for horizontal scroll. Otherwise, the ListView will throw a "constraints are unbounded" error.

For your use case, you can either set height on the list items in the first ListView, or set height on the second ListView. However, if you'd like the second ListView to be non-scrollable and the list items in the first ListView will adapt dynamically, you can use a Column of Widgets similar to this sample.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final items = [
    'Apple',
    'Banana',
    'Carrot',
    'Dog',
    'Egg',
    'Flower',
    'Goat',
    'Honey'
  ];

  final subItems = ['1.00', '2.00', '3.00', '4.00'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: firstList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  firstList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text('${items[index]}'),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: secondList(subItems),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  secondList(List item) {
    // Create List<Widget> for the second "List"
    var subList = List<Widget>();
    item.forEach((data) {
      subList.add(
        Card(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Text('$data'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
    // Populate Column instead of ListView
    return Column(
      children: subList,
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]